# IQ Retail API not returning Invoice data

Tags: c#, dbisam

I am trying to do an invoice request on IQIntAPI and I am getting the below error message

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<IQ_API_Result>
   <IQ_API_Error>
      <IQ_Error_Code>5</IQ_Error_Code>
      <IQ_Error_Description>Unable to open Data Tables for Company [FMC]</IQ_Error_Description>
      <IQ_Error_Data>
         <IQ_Error_Data_Item>
            <IQ_Error_Code>7</IQ_Error_Code>
            <IQ_Error_Description>IQ_User_Password Is Invalid</IQ_Error_Description>
            <IQ_Error_Extended_Data />
         </IQ_Error_Data_Item>
         <IQ_Error_Data_Item>
            <IQ_Error_Code>5</IQ_Error_Code>
            <IQ_Error_Description>Unable to open Data Tables for Company [FMC]</IQ_Error_Description>
            <IQ_Error_Extended_Data />
         </IQ_Error_Data_Item>
      </IQ_Error_Data>
   </IQ_API_Error>
</IQ_API_Result>
```

Company_Number, IQ_Terminal_Number, IQ_User_Number and IQ_User_Password is correct for the API user
I have tried running the REST Server, giving all access permissions to Company Folder but the API still gives the same error.Below is part of my sourcecode:

```
IntPtr FResult;
            string FResultString;
            int FResultLength;
            string FMessage;
            int FMessageLength;
            int FCallResult;

            StringWriter FStringWriter = new StringWriter();

            using (XmlWriter FWriter = XmlWriter.Create(FStringWriter))
            {
                FWriter.WriteStartDocument();

                FWriter.WriteStartElement("IQ_API");
                FWriter.WriteStartElement("IQ_API_Request_Document_Invoice");
                FWriter.WriteElementString("IQ_Company_Number", "FMC");
                FWriter.WriteElementString("IQ_Terminal_Number", "1");
                FWriter.WriteElementString("IQ_User_Number", "100");
                FWriter.WriteElementString("IQ_User_Password", "KIDD");
                FWriter.WriteEndElement(); //IQ_API_Request_Stock                   
                FWriter.WriteEndElement(); //IQ_API                
                FWriter.WriteEndDocument();
                FWriter.Flush();
            }


            FMessage = FStringWriter.ToString();
            FMessageLength = FMessage.Length;
            FResultLength = 0;

            FCallResult = IQ_API_Request_Document_Invoice(FMessage, FMessageLength, out FResult, ref FResultLength);
            FResultString = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(FResult);

            if (FCallResult != 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("An Error Occurred. Error Code [" + FCallResult.ToString() + "]");
            }
            lstResult.Text = FormatXML(FResultString.Substring(0, FResultLength));
```

Where might I be going wrong in my source code or IQ Retail setup?

Comment: The first point of contact should be the commercial source for thr api, after all you are paying for this. I mean who knows what the documentation says or what bugs they have

Comment: The error message says following : IQ_User_Password Is Invalid

Comment: Sure but that's a valid password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My response may be very late, but I hope my answer will help the next person in the future to solve this issue.

If you are using **'IQEntAPITest.exe'** which you will typically find in this directory

> C:\IQRetail\IQEnterprise\IQEntAPITest.exe

or where ever you've installed IQ, you can use your password as it is. **IQEntAPITest** converts the password in the background for you into SHA1, hence you can use your direct password.

In this case, you are not using IQEntAPITest, therefore you will need to [SHA1](http://www.sha1-online.com/) your password and make sure the letters in the newly generated SHA1 password are in upper-case. Copy and paste that password in your code. You should be fine.